# jquery error function help

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not much of a javascript guy but I would like to implement error dialogs in this project I'm working on. I want to send a http header that the error function will catch and display the correct message. I've already tested the error function with an alert box and when I send a header 400, the error function is triggered.

Is it possible in JQuery or javascript to show different messages / dialogs based on the header code like 400 or 401? Based on that code then show the user the proper error message? I have about 4 or 5 messages that I need to show per error function

```
error:function(){
    // call my dialog here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `statusCode` option is available in jQuery 1.5+ for [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax):

> A map of numeric HTTP codes and functions to be called when the response has the corresponding code. For example, the following will alert when the response status is a 404:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

> If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; if it results in an error, they take the same parameters as the error callback.

Comment: Thanks Vivin. OK, here is where I'm really going to show my noobie spots and ask a dumb question. Doesn't the JQ plugin I'm working with need to developed to use the ajax function first?

Comment: @eric Ah, I didn't know that - you should mention that in your question :) I thought that you were using just jQuery. What plugin are you using? And yes, if the plugin that you're using doesn't give you access to that information or that behavior, you won't be able to do what you want to do.

Comment: It doesn't look like that plugin gives you any of that information in the `error` callback unfortunately.

Comment: OK. Can you tell me what my options are for multiple error dialogs? Is it possible? I can get one just fine but I have many sanity checks on the data being saved and need to show the user the appropriate error message.

Comment: I don't think you would be able to do multiple error dialogs with your current setup. This is because the `error` callback doesn't give you enough information so that you can customize the error you display to the user. You can only tell the user that an error occurred. If you want more fine-grained control, you would have to write something yourself that uses `jQuery.ajax`. Or, see if you modify the source of the plugin to make it do what you want.

Comment: OK Vivin, thanks a lot for the help. I'm not too javascript savvy but I'll look at the source.